# pdflatex, \includegraphics, and multi-page PDF files

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages

I have a PDF file with multiple figures; each figure is a separate page in the PDF file.

I am using `pdflatex`, and I would like to use `\includegraphics` or equivalent to include some of the figures.

Of course I could use an external tool to split the PDF file into multiple one-page PDF files. Then I could use `\includegraphics` as usual. However, I would have a much simpler workflow if I could avoid this extra step. Hence the question:

**How can I include, e.g., page 3 of `foo.pdf` as a figure?**

I am aware that there is a Latex package called `pdfpages`, but it seems to be designed for something else: with `pdfpages`, each page in the input file will produce a *full page* in the final document, not just a box.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`graphicx` (the extended version of `graphics`) knows the `page` option:

```
\includegraphics[page=3]{foo}
```

should work, or

```
\includegraphics[page=..,trim=...,clip]{foo}
```

for only parts of the page. If you want to include more than one page then use Package `pdfpages` and the command `\includepdf`

Comment: Many thanks, it indeed works! I was already writing that I would like to do something like `\includegraphics[page=3]{foo}`, but didn't try it, as I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation of the `graphicx` package... Thus a follow-up question that might help me and others in the future: where is the `page=` option documented?

Comment: that is defined only for the driver `pdftex`, the reason why you find it not in `graphicx`, but in the file `pdftex.def`

Comment: But that effectively means that it's not documented at all, since pdftex.def certainly isn't where anyone should look for such information, and other that a single mention that the `graphicx` package has "automatic pdfTeX support", the pdftex documentation isn't really helpful either. (I've been using graphicx for years and didn't know about this either.)

Comment: @Alan: the problem is that most people think that graphicx inserts the graphic, but it didn't, it provides only the useful infos for TeX or pdftex for typesetting. pdftex itself also didn't know anything about the graphic format, but it is the only system, which has its own driver. The others have only drivers for external programs, like dvips, dvipsone, dvipdf and so on. The file `pdftex.def` has some more useful features. I understand your point, but it is not me who provides pdftex.def ... :-)

Comment: Anyone knows how to put not a entire page, but just a piece.
I mean, just 60% of one page in a pdf file.

Comment: @João: use `\includegraphics[page=..,trim=...,clip]{file.pdf}`

Comment: \includegraphics[page=3]{foo}
includes ONLY page number 3 for me. Any idea on that?? thanks!

Comment: @marinko: `\includegraphics` _always_ includes ONE page. If you want more then use `\includepdf`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this still works for xelatex.

Comment: I seem to observe that the document compilation becomes _much slower_, while including pages in this fashion. Anyone else observed the same? I will try splitting pages to separate PDFs, benchmark and report, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

Here another possibility using graphics package. In this way you can include each one of the pages than you want from your pdf file ([page= number of the page in the pdf file that you want to include). In the example I want to include a big table that I do in pdf having 2 pages and including that in the TOC like table.

```
\begingroup

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

    \begin{center}
    %\fbox{
    \includegraphics[page=1, width=\linewidth]{Foo}%}
    \end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}

    \begin{center}
    %\fbox{
    \includegraphics[page=2, width=\linewidth]{Foo}%}
    \captionof{table}{Caption}
    \label{Zones_intervention_tab}
    \end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\endgroup
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Useful inofrmations [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Have fun with LaTex.