# multipage pdf as separate image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pdflatex, \includegraphics, and multi-page PDF files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/pdflatex-includegraphics-and-multi-page-pdf-files)

Sometimes I create a multi-page pdf as output, e.g. graphs from R.

Is there a possibility which allows me to select separate pages of a pdf as source for the graphic that will be typeset in Latex?

Comment: indeed, the question is very similar... you can close this one if you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can select which page to include by using `\includegraphics[page=<number>]{filename}` from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: wow, that was exactly what i was looking for!, thanks.. this will make my Figures directory alot less crowded

Comment: Can I use multiple pages at one go?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package for including whole pages of the pdf, you can select page ranges by using the `pages` option:

```
\includepdf[pages=1]{filename}
\includepdf[pages={2,4}]{filename}
```