# Insert Image from multipage pdf file in Lyx

Tags: graphics, pdf, lyx, pdfpages

I am writing a report and I have all the images in a pdf file with very high resolution. With limited skills in editing, I am loosing the quality of the image when I try to save the individual images.

I am wondering, if there is any option in LyX to include the images directly from the pdf file  by specifying the page number. I happen to stumble across this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19134/multipage-pdf-as-separate-image-in-latex) which I can use in LaTeX. Is it possible to do similarly in LyX as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Insert -> File -> External Material*, which wraps the `pdfpages` package. [Documentation for pdfpages is available here](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

Another way which might be more appropriate is to insert the `.pdf` file as if it were any other graphic (*Insert -> Graphics...*) and use the `page=n` option. These options are passed to the `\includegraphics` command, which is part of the `graphicx` package ([which is documented here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics)). A screen shot follows:

[image: graphics configuration]

Here are some screenshots of the `pdfpages` method:

[image: external material dialog]

[image: external material options dialog]

Comment: Alex, Thanks a lot, is is possible to scale it, rotate it just like normal images. I donot  see any option here for that

Comment: Yes. I have updated the above post to include a method which uses the `graphicx` package which adds the standard LyX capabilities for images. Note that there will be cases where either method is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for the timely help. I am using the graphicx package in my report.

Comment: The `graphicx` way works partly for me. In the lyx window itself it only shows me the first page (for any page I chose). is there a way to see the actual page in the lyx window?