# Multipage pdf not displaying correctly in Lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx, pdf

I have a pdf file with multiple images that I want to insert into my Lyx document as individual images. I've managed to successfully do it as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28298/insert-image-from-multipage-pdf-file-in-lyx) using the `\includegraphics` method.

However, in the Lyx GUI itself, the image that is displayed is either the first or last page, no matter what page I specify. The final output is correct, so this is more a quality of life issue so I can quickly see that I've added the correct page, or need to trim the image.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the converter. I'm using Lyx 2.0.6, and this happens on both OSX and Windows.

Example:

Inserted pdfs not showing correct page in Lyx

[image]

But correctly generated pdf file
[image]

Comment: I believe this is just how it was implemented in LyX. You can file an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac. There might be one already for this but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

LyX uses its converter framework to convert images you insert into a format that LyX can display. Here it is converting from PDF to EPS. Looking at the converter in Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters by selecting "PDF(graphics) -> EPS", you will see that the converter is

```
pdftops -eps -f 1 -l 1 $$i $$o
```

`man pdftops` shows the following:

> OPTIONS
>
> ```
>    -f number
>           Specifies the first page to print.
>
>    -l number
>           Specifies the last page to print.
> ```

If you file an [enhancement request](http://www.lyx.org/trac), please link back to this question.