# includegraphics[page=\pageref... possible? how to set [page=] to a variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, cross-referencing, include

I'm currently writing a quite complex document with a lot of graphics created using TikZ. Hence I decided to put all graphics into one big file called tikz.tex creating a multiple page PDF with one tightly cropped page per graphic.

The `tikz.tex` (which I compile separately) generates a clean PDF and .aux file.
Here is a minimal version of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\tikzset{
    %... my tikzset ...
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{preview}
        \label{pic1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %... tikz ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
    \begin{preview}
        \label{pic2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %... tikz ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
\end{document}
```

the minimal version of my Master file

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage {xr}
\usepackage []{hyperref}
\externaldocument[tikz:]{../Bilder/tikz}
\begin{document}
    \input{../Kapitel/Kapitel_1}
\end{document}
```

a minimal version of the actual chapter, which is included in the master file, would look similar to this

```
\chapter{name}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[page=\pageref{tikz:pic2}]{../Bilder/tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

this returns:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \protect l.12
...KOS},width=\textwidth]{../Bilder/tikz.pdf} A number should have
been here; I inserted `0'.
```

The idea was to use the labels in my main document to refer to the correct page number. of course i could just hard code the page number but since I intend to use this tikz file for quite some time I'd prefer referencing the page number by `\pageref` or something similar. I do not want to split the PDF into single files.

It works if my chapter looks like this. in this case the `\pageref` is shown correct

```
\chapter{name}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[page=2]{../Bilder/tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}
correct page number of pic 2 is \pageref{tikz:pic2}
```

Any ideas how to get `\includegraphics[page=\pageref{...}]` working?

Thanks **a lot** in advance!

Comment: Note that chapters are usually inserted in the main document using `\include` not `\input`. See e.g. [When should I use \input vs \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for more details.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/using-pdf-bookmarks-to-refer-to-pages-in-includegraphics and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number

Comment: Your right, I should rather use \include but since its the standard layout of my department and the slow down is acceptable changing this would be a lot of work and, for the time being, unnecessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the [`zref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) package for this. It comes with a `zref-xr` module (i.e. sub-package, i.e. package) and allows to extract the page number from reverences as plain number which can be used in `\includegraphics`. The normal `\pageref` usually included other code which makes it unsuitable.
You might need to fully expand the page number before you pass it to the `page` key of `\includegraphics`. It is also possible to define your own key just for this purpose.

A minimal example would be:

```
% tikzstuff.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
    \begin{preview}
        \zlabel{pic1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (10,10);
            \node at (5,5) {\large\sffamily 1};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
    \begin{preview}
        \zlabel{pic2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,10) -- (10,0);
            \node at (5,5) {\large\sffamily 2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
\end{document}
```

for the TikZ diagram and the following main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xr]{zref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\zexternaldocument[tikz:]{tikzstuff}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{bylabel}{%
    \edef\@tempa{{Gin}{page=\zref@extract{tikz:#1}{page}}}%
    \expandafter\setkeys\@tempa
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

...

\includegraphics[bylabel=pic1]{tikzstuff}% Include image reference as 'pic1' in the external document

...

\includegraphics[bylabel=pic2]{tikzstuff}

\end{document}
```

---

Note that you could just place every TikZ picture in an own file and use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) bundle to compile them on their own while also be able to insert them into a main document. This saves you the issues with the page references.

Comment: That works just like i wanted, **thanks a lot!** I used the standalone package before I decided to put everything into one file. by this i can create some sort of graphics library which I can use for all my future related work. yet splitting up a picture or inserting one variant of it doesnt effect referencing due to new page numbers anymore.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
\chapter{name}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \edef\temp{page=\pageref{tikz:pic2}}
    \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\temp]{../Bilder/tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: That would only expand the `p` of `page` before `\includegraphics`. When `hyperref` is loaded `\pageref` isn't expandable anyway, AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinScharrer This would correctly expand `\temp`; but the remark about the unexpandability of `\pageref` is correct. Loading the **refcount** package one can use `\getpagerefnumber` that is expandable.

Comment: @egreg: My comment was about the first version which didn't used `\temp`. The hint to `refcount` is good. I didn't know it before.