# Passing (a lot of) parameters to a file at compilation time

Tags: packages, compiling

It is possible to pass some parameters when compiling a `myfile.tex` file:

```
pdflatex "\some\parameters\input{myfile}"
```

But, if the number of parameters increase, this is not very practicable. So I'd like to store them in a file (possibly a personal package), say `myparameters.sty`, and load them at the compilation time. Of course:

```
pdflatex "\input{myparameters.sty}\input{myfile}"
```

doesn't work as the compiled file is `myparameters.sty`. But, whereas the following file (say `supermyfile.tex`):

```
\RequirePackage{myparameters}
\input{myfile}
```

compiles like a charm with:

```
pdflatex supermyfile
```

the following:

```
pdflatex "\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{myfile}"
```

doesn't work as the compiled file is `myparameters.sty` here as well.

Hence my question: how to pass (a lot of) parameters to a file at compilation time?

Comment: try `pdflatex -jobname myfile "\input{myparameters.sty}\input{myfile}"`

Comment: I would recommend defining flags for the various compiles that you have. Assuming you don't have hunderds of different possible combinations, I would recommend have [conditionals](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577) in your standard `myparameters.sty` and defining the parameters based on flags that you set on the command line.  For example `\ifdefined\DebugMode ... \else ... \fi`, `\ifdefined\VerboseMode ... \else ... \fi`., etc.

Comment: @Herbert It doesn't work with `\input{myparameters.sty}` (and that would probably be not easy to debug) but it does with `\RequirePackage{myparameters}`. Now, I just have to see how to include this command line in a `latexmk` process.

Comment: @PeterGrill In fact I have only one alternative: either the parameters are passed or they don't. But my use case is a bit particular: `myfile.tex` is a sample file using a class I'm working on and is intended 1) to be screenshots for the class doc (this involves parameters in order to extract the relevant pages, thanks to `zref` package and [this method](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31485/18401)); 2) to be compiled by users who want to try the class (and, for this, it is required to not disturb the file with strange parameters).

Comment: or you could simply do: `\def\myfile{parameters}\input{file}` and in `file` do: `\ifdefined\myfile\input{\myfile}\fi`

Comment: @zeroth Well, I'm not sure to understand. To precise what I told @PeterGrill, `myfile.tex` is in `.../texmf/doc/latex/myclass/sample/` and, with a symlink, in `.../texmf/source/latex/myclass/sample/`. I want to let `myfile.tex` intact in `.../texmf/source/latex/myclass/sample/` but apply in this directory some parameters useful for the class documentation whose source is in `.../texmf/source/latex/myclass/`.

Comment: I managed to include the command line `pdflatex -jobname myfile
"\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{myfile}"` in a latexmk process with
`latexmk -pdf -jobname=myfile -pdflatex="pdflatex %O
'\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{%S}'" myfile.tex`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: What I meant is that since you say `pdflatex supermyfile` works, place all your code in `myparameters`, and on the command line say something line `pdflatex "\def\ModeA{}\input{supermyfile}`", and in `myparameters` define all the conditions required for `ModeA`, etc. I think if you provided a more detailed example of exactly what you want things might be simpler. If it is a list of pages you could define a list on the command line as well.

Comment: @PeterGrill Okay, I've understood. But I prefer to work with only one file (the original one). Hence I'm happy with `pdflatex -jobname myfile "\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{myfile}"`. I don't know f I can answer my question myself with that answer.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: Yes, self answers are perfectly acceptable. But, with your solution you are still working with two files.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't see your point when you say that I'm still working with two files: only the `myfile.tex` file (okay, twice, but via a symlink) is involved, and not the two files `myfile.tex` and `supermyfile.tex`.

Comment: The two files being: `myfile.tex` and the required package `myparameters.sty`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Oh, yes, of course! I meant I prefered to work with only one `.tex` file (the original one).

Comment: That was what I was suggesting: One `.tex` file and one `myparameters.sty` file that had the conditionals defined for all the various settings that you desire to control form the command line.

Comment: @PeterGrill OK, understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Herbert's suggestion, here is the (at least an) answer to my question. It is possible to pass (a lot of) parameters to a `.tex` file (say `myfile.tex`) at compilation time, by storing them in a personal package (say `myparameters.sty`) and by running:

```
pdflatex -jobname myfile "\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{myfile}"
```

Moreover, this can be included in a `latexmk` process with:

```
latexmk -pdf -jobname=myfile -pdflatex="pdflatex %O '\RequirePackage{myparameters}\input{%S}'" myfile.tex
```

Comment: I can't see why `\input{myparameters}` shouldn't work, if the file is `myparameters.tex`; or `\input{myparameters.sty}` if you prefer this name.

Comment: Indeed, except extra `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` may be needed in case of `\input` instead of `\RequirePackage`.