# Figures from PDF pages according to their labeleing in latex

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

I have dozens of figures in my latex named all differently. I want to put them into a single PDF file and call each figure from there via something like `\includegraphics[page="label3"]{foo}` instead of `\includegraphics[page=3]{foo}`. In other words I want to call figures from a PDF according to their proper labeling [assigned in creation of this single PDF file containing all figures].

Comment: May we know why? I'm happy to have each image in a different file, so I can change them at will. So they don't clutter everything up, I've got the segregated into a directory.

Comment: For my thesis. I don't want to zip figures and instead send thesis.tex and a pdf.

Comment: What's wrong with a zipfile, or a tar? My thesis was a dozen or so troff files (yes, a _long_ time back), my current lecture notes is 41 LaTeX files and 240 images, and a bunch or supporting/scaffolding.

Comment: Then I have to explain how to unzip and where to put folder etc. By the way, my question is similar to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/using-pdf-bookmarks-to-refer-to-pages-in-includegraphics?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by defining the labels to macros which expand to the page number. I would use a custom macro to first create the multi-page PDF and then, with a different definition, to create the label list.

Because this is difficult to understand here some code:

Create a `.tex` file which contains only the following:

```
% filelist.tex
\myimagelist{some label}{some path/pdffile1}
\myimagelist{some other label}{some path/pdffile2}
% ....
```

To create the multi-page document use the following document:

```
% allpdfs.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\myimagelist}[2]{\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\input{filelist}
\end{document}
```

This will put every (single page) PDF as a page of the resulting PDF, where every page still has to original size.

In your real document could look like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\csname mylabel #1\endcsname}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\myimagelist}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{mycounter}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname mylabel #1\endcsname{\arabic{mycounter}}%
}
\input{filelist}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[page=\mylabel{some label}]{allpdfs}

or use:

\newcommand{\imagebylabel}[2][]{\includegraphics[page=\mylabel{#2},#1]{allpdfs}}

\imagebylabel{some other label}

\end{document}
```

I couldn't test the code, because I'm currently sitting on a family PC without installed LaTeX, but you should get the principle idea.

Comment: I have tried you code. First, the figures are all in the 8x11 inch pages, instead of in their original sizes. Second, in the main document I am getting following error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \mylabel ...{\mylabel}[1]{\csname mylabel #2\endcsname}
Missing number, treated as zero ...aphics[page=\mylabel{some label}]{allpdfs}
Missing \endcsname inserted ...aphics[page=\mylabel{some label}]{allpdfs}

Comment: The `#2` should be a `#1` and I forgot the `fitpaper` option for `\includepdf`. I edited my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Martin, is there a way to include EPS figures in the filelist.tex?

Comment: @Lara: You need to convert them to PDF first, e.g. using `epstopdf` or a similar tool.

Comment: Martin, one last question. Is there any easy way to create bookmarks in allpdfs according to the figure titles [or their labels]?