# Embedding a LaTeX document inside another, with some border or other stylising

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, embedding

I'm writing a fairly lengthy report, which should include several papers I have worked on.

Each paper is more-or-less self contained, with their own title, date, sections, etc. I have each of these papers as both .tex and .pdf files.

In my report, I would like to somehow embed the papers but I want it to be very obvious that there is an embedded document.

For example, when I do a quote, the margins are brought in and the text is smaller.

I would like there to maybe be a border, or very slightly darker background, or something so that the reader can clearly see that they are reading a paper I have worked on in the past, within the report that mentions it.

I know about \usepackage{pdfpages}, however this simply put the pdf inside the document as is. The sectioning numbers suddenly revert to 1, and they return to where they were once the embedded pdf ends.

What's the best way to do what I need? Should I just copy the contents of the .tex files and change the sections to subsections and so on, and just put that LaTeX code inside my report?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: You may find this helpful as a place to start: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7939/28808 -- I'm thinking wrap that in a loop and you're nearly there.

Comment: I'll leave my original comment for now, but I'd only scratched the surface of the `pdfpages` package and not read the documentation, until now: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf -- look at combining it with `\pagecolor`.

Comment: I use the following:         \includepdfset{pages=-,nup=2x3,frame,noautoscale=false,delta=5mm 5mm,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}}        to basically include small versions of slides in a handout. Obviously not what you want but you can definitely use a frame. The \thispagestyle command is telling it to use the standard headers/footers (I use the package for fancy headers/footers - obviously change to whatever style you use).